# when i import javascript files to angular i found Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')

Tags: angular

```
**the js files doesnt see the component element**
```

the error occured in this js function
the (showMenu,perspective,cont,wrapper) return null
And  I get the following error when I launch my app

```
function init() {
        var showMenu = document.getElementById( 'showMenu' ),
            perspectiveWrapper = document.getElementById( 'perspective' ),
            cont = perspectiveWrapper.querySelector( '.cont' ),
            contentWrapper = cont.querySelector( '.wrapper' );
            

       
    }

    init();
```

Here is the index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Assignment1</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body >
      <app-root></app-root>
 <!-- javascript libraries -->
    <script src="/assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/jquery.appear.min.js"></script>
    <!-- push nav -->
    <script src="/assets/js/push_nav.js"></script>
</body>
   
   
</html>
```

Here is my component.ts and i get an ERROR ReferenceError: Init is not defined at HomeComponent.ngAfterViewInit

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewEncapsulation  } from '@angular/core';
declare function init():any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,

})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { 
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit():void{
    init();
  }

}
```

Comment: What is the structure of your project? Like how and where is your JavaScript declared or imported?

Comment: in angular.json in "scripts": []

Comment: okay great, but then I can see you included javascript libraries outside body but inside html tag. Also, it is possible that at the time your init function is called, the elements don't yet exist, like Angular has not yet filled the DOM with the html that your custom js is trying to detect. firstly, I will suggest you move the logic of the custom js to a component, because I mean you are in Angular. And if there are valid reasons why you can't do that, then expose a variable from the js file and attach the init function to it.

Comment: then in the component where it html elements are found, you do variable.init inside ngAfterViewInit lifecycle method. You might also have to do `declare var variablename` at the top of that typescript file. I should have posted all these as an answer but there is more to your code you are not sharing. Like the error message for example or the custom file or the htmls you are trying to access and all

Comment: i tried this and i recived this ERROR ReferenceError: Init is not defined
    at HomeComponent.ngAfterViewInit

Comment: no not declare var init, we need to see the js code you are importing. you can have var external = { init } in the JS code. Then in the component, do declare var external and you call but external.init() This will work if the js is properly added in angular.json. You should restart the angular serving if you make changes to angular.json

Comment: ```  var external = { 
 varinit()
 {
   var showMenu = document.getElementById( 'showMenu' ),
    perspectiveWrapper =document.getElementById( 'perspective' ),
    cont = perspectiveWrapper.querySelector( '.cont' ),
    contentWrapper = cont.querySelector( '.wrapper' ) ;
 }
}```

Comment: and i did what you say in component but it still cant reach to js file

Comment: declare var external:any

Comment: ngAfterViewInit():void{
    external.varinit();
  }

Comment: this is a small problem but you need to provide much code and your setup, okay consider providing a minimum reproducible of what you have in stackblitz, so from there we can fork and edit

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-download-yg3zod?file=src/index.html

Comment: at first site, this is angular and your home.component.html is not what I expect. You can be having a full html with head and meta tags and body inside an angular component. That alone makes things go wrong you see

Comment: you are right it's worked thanks allot

Comment: so have you solved the problem ? if yes, please post the answer and accept it as answer to help those who might land on your question in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in component.ts write this to link js file with component.html

```
myScriptElement: HTMLScriptElement ;
this.myScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
    this.myScriptElement.src ="/assets/js/push_nav.js";
    document.body.appendChild(this.myScriptElement);
```

Comment: wow didn't expect this though, but glad it worked. But truth be told, this is some sort of anti-pattern, like it defeats the reason why Angular was created.

Answer (score 2):

You sure about the method name you're calling

**Init()**

or

**init()**

Comment: i edited it and still have the same error message

Comment: Try for testing purposes move your init function into your component. Hard to tell without having a full project to step through the flow to see what all is visible.